# jQuery UI Date Picker on Android?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery UI Date Picker on mobile web and testing in Android 2.3 device.  It's currently working well (with the default out of the box behaviors), but I am having one distinct issue.  When the date picker opens, any additional input fields below the dp will also be selected when a date is clicked, highlighting the field on top of the date picker.  How do I fix this issue?  Is it a focus thing?  I can post code if it's needed, but again, this is all default jQuery ui.  Also, this is not an issue in iOS 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I could not find which event had to be stopped from propagating. Did you find a solution?

My current workaround is:
- deactivate inputs, selects etc when you open the dialog
- reactivate them when you close the dialog.

It is working fine when you do this (but it should not be necessary).

Comment: The company I work for decided against using jQuery because of the added file size.  I'm currently writing my own datepicker from scratch, no js libs.  Ping me your email address, and I'll send you the scripts.  All in all, it'll be under 10kb in size, perfect for 3G devices.

Comment: Your above solution is exactly the path I took as well.  If there is another way around this, I'm all ears...

Comment: Here is the official Android bug regarding this issue.  A couple of work-arounds exists, but nothing perfect... I used comment #33 which is basically the same advice as above, but with code.  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6721